# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4' Atom MacOS

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, atom-editor, python-venv, modulenotfounderror

I am currently using Atom on Mac, and I get `ModuleNotFoundError`: No module named 'bs4' when I execute my program.

I have tried the following solutions, but it did not fix the problem:

- Used a virtual environment using venv

  ```
  python3 -m venv projectname
  source projectname/bin/activate
  pip install bs4
  ```
- Installed bs4 using different names:

  ```
  pip install bs4
  pip install beautifulsoup4
  pip install BeautifulSoup4
  ```

All of which gives me the message, "Requirement already satisfied"

- Deleting and reinstalling bs4
- Setting the Atom Python to 'python3' under Atom config > packages > script > lib > grammars >  python.coffee

I referenced multiple StackOverflow solutions similar to my question, but I was unable to solve the issue. Could there be something wrong about python on my laptop, or the setting in Atom?

If so, may I know what specific steps I will have to take? Thank you in advance.

My Setup:

Atom 1.55.0

Python 3.7.6

MacOSCatalina 10.15.5

Comment: Is Atom using the Python executable from the venv?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if Atom is using the python executable from the venv. May I know how to do it? However, even if I do execute my python file from the terminal with the venv activated, it still gives me the modulenotfound error.

Comment: Did you Activated Your Virtual Env and Installed bs4 in that ??

Comment: try install with sudo
`sudo pip install bs4`
or
`sudo pip3 install bs4`

Comment: @Giorgi Please don't suggest using sudo with pip (unless the virtualenv is actually owned by root)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using `python3 -m venv`, you can equivalently use `python3 -m pip install`

Otherwise, it appears you're PATH has `pip` binary pointing at some other Python, and maybe you should try `pip3`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried both python3 -m pip install, and pip3. However, I am still getting the same error. Is there a specific way I could change the PATH?

Comment: You could use pyenv along with pyenv-virtualenvwrapper which manage that for you. Otherwise, sounds like an Atom misconfiguration and I've not really used it in years, but I know Vscode has good Python virtualenv support. Then again, if running your script directly from the terminal gives the same error, then you have other Python issues that need fixed first... Also worth pointing out that bs4 is not the correct pip installable https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-beautiful-soup